# G++ basepath for cpp-files

Tags: c++

I downloaded a library with a lot of cpp and header files. Including the header path is no problem (-I) But compiler doesn't find cpp-files. How to "include" the cpp-file-folder as parameter? I already tried -I, but this seems only to work with header files.

a.cpp(own project file) x.cpp, y.cpp(library files in c:\src):

g++ -Ic:\src -Ic:\header a.cpp x.cpp y.cpp --> doesn't work

Comment: Can you link to this library?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Either you compile and link the library separately and then link your program against that library, or - if the license of your library allows that - you compile all source files (including those from the library) and link everything together into your final program.